# oracle: Procedure with case

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by, case, procedure

Why this procedure doesn't work?
I tried to get by cursor the rows of the table: AF_EMPLOYEE, and this will order with ASC/DESC (according to the case).

```
Create or Replace Procedure return_rows_EMPLOYEE (in_order in number, 
in_sorting in VARCHAR2, in_job in VARCHAR2, out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) As
Begin
  OPEN out_cursor for
  select * from AF_EMPLOYEE
  WHERE EMPL_JOB_TITLE = in_job
  ORDER BY in_sorting
  CASE in_order
  WHEN 1 THEN   ASC
  ELSE  DESC
  END
End;
```

Comment: Please add more description of question.

Comment: So, `in_order=1` should mean `ASC`, otherwise `DESC`. What column do you want to be sorted?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Create or Replace Procedure return_rows_EMPLOYEE (in_order in number, 
in_sorting in VARCHAR2, in_job in VARCHAR2, out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) As
Begin
  if in_order = 1 THEN
     OPEN out_cursor for
     select * from AF_EMPLOYEE
     WHERE EMPL_JOB_TITLE = in_job
     ORDER BY in_sorting ASC
  else
     OPEN out_cursor for
     select * from AF_EMPLOYEE
     WHERE EMPL_JOB_TITLE = in_job
     ORDER BY in_sorting DESC
  end if;
End;
```

**Update**
try this:

```
Create or Replace Procedure return_rows_EMPLOYEE (in_order in number, 
in_sorting in VARCHAR2, in_job in VARCHAR2, out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) As
Begin
  OPEN out_cursor for
  select * from AF_EMPLOYEE
  WHERE EMPL_JOB_TITLE = in_job
  ORDER BY 
  case when in_order = 1 then
      in_sorting 
  end,
  case when in_order <> 1 then
      in_sorting
  end desc;
End;
```

Comment: Thanks. But i need that with Case, It is possible? @paubo147

Comment: This doesn't work too. I got this error:
Error(6,6): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(9,3): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Error(15,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:     if

Comment: changed! Tell me, if it works. I have no access to a database to test this now.

Comment: @paubo147 ...no access to a database..., may be sqlfiddle.com can help?

Comment: @paubo147 I added a ";" after order By line, and it's work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the sort column is numeric, you can use `case` to negate it, but it's not good code!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE return_rows_EMPLOYEE (in_order in number, 
in_sorting in VARCHAR2, in_job in VARCHAR2, out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) As
Begin
  OPEN out_cursor for
  select * from AF_EMPLOYEE
  WHERE EMPL_JOB_TITLE = in_job
  ORDER BY 
    CASE in_sorting WHEN 'ASC'  THEN  sort_column 
                    WHEN 'DESC' THEN -sort_column 
     END;
END; 
/
```